# Problem with HTTP POST

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

While making postdata, if i use & as boundary, everything seems to be fine. If i change that to some other string, say &&, it fails with unknown error, once i get response.

i use:

```
request.Headers["boundary"] = "&&"; //--> which leads to a failure(exception)
```

when i use & as boundary in postdata, even if don't mention in request.Headers["boundary"], result is same(success).

Can somebody throw some light on how to set boundary?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I get The "remote server returned an error: NotFound"

Comment: Why do you need to set a custom boundary?

Comment: not sure. I'm new to http, afaik, coz server is designed to serve requests from different mobile platforms, this is to get some consistency?

Comment: you mean & is default and that cannot be changed? what if my data has few & chars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN seems to suggest that `Boundary` isn't a header that you can set.
List of supported headers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httprequestheader(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: thanks for link, you mean & is default and that cannot be changed? what if my data has few & chars? or default boundary chars?

Comment: @rplusg if your data contains ampersands you should encode them appropriately. Just like other reserved characters